# Speeding and optimizing the Graphics Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, code-review, code-request

I am having a Hermitian Matrix(`HCF[k]`) depending on a parameter $k$.

My job is to plot the Eigenvalues of the matrix as the parameter $k$ is changed.

But I am facing some problems.
(i) My Mathematica file size, which is of around whopping 90Mb, when `HCF[k]` is around $284\times284$.
(ii) This part of code is very slow as the size of `HCF[k]` is increasing.

```
kdel = 0.00001; (* offset *)
kIn = -π - kdel;  (*Initial value of k *)
kFin = π + kdel;  (*Final value of k *)
kInc = 0.001; (*Increment of k*)

eigeng = 
 ParallelTable[Eigenvalues[HCF[k]], {k, kIn, kFin, kInc}];


kList = ParallelTable[k, {k, kIn, kFin, kInc}];


kFList = ParallelTable[kList, {i, Transpose@eigeng}];

dataToPlot = Flatten[{kFList\[Transpose], eigeng}\[Transpose], {{1, 3}, {2}}];

Graphics[{Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ dataToPlot, Frame -> True,
...(* for the aesthetic of plot, i.e. axis title, range and bla bla*)]
```

- *Is there a way the size issue can be overcome?*
- *Is there a way the code can be sped up a little bit?(I checked
  my rest of the code, it is very fast, which I did by breaking and
  evaluating it into small cells).*

**Addendum**

- Form of `HCF[k]`, as it is huge I will try to show you how it looks for small size say
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
   -20 \pi  & -\frac{e^{i k}}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
   -\frac{1}{2} e^{-i k} & -20 \pi  & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{e^{i k}}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
   -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} e^{-i k} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 20 \pi  & -\frac{e^{i k}}{2} \\
   0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} e^{-i k} & 20 \pi  \\
  \end{array}
  \right)

Comment: What does `HCF` look like?

Comment: @MarcoB Please see the edit, _similar form_ may look like for 284X284.

Comment: Please post code, not LaTeX, so one can copy/paste it. It would be best if you could either propose a smaller version of your matrix, or simply post the whole matrix somewhere (e.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Also, your `kList` and `kFList` do not need to be defined using `ParallelTable`; a simple `Range` would work, and probably be faster too. In general, have you tried without parallelization? Are you sure that parallel execution leads to a speedup?

Comment: @MarcoB Here you will find the [Matrix(paste bin, thanks for this)](http://pastebin.com/bsSaEYzt). I always thought `Parallel` does work fast(may be I was in some illusion). So, never thought of out of parallelization. I am sorry I can't give the code that generated the matrix as there is some work going on(some restrictions on me), I really hope you will understand it(take it good). _I gave you the matrix and your help will definitely show some **light** on the problem_.

Comment: @MarcoB How `kFList` using `Range`, I failed in doing that. But able to do the `kList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses your definitions of the matrix from pastebin, and of starting points and increments.

Parallelization does help to speed up the calculation of the eigenvalues, but you have to distribute the definitions of your helper variables to the parallel kernels using `DistributeDefinitions` first:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Eigenvalues[mat], {k, kIn, kFin, kInc}];]
(* Out: {142.851, Null} *)

DistributeDefinitions[kdel, kIn, kFin, kInc]
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Eigenvalues[mat], {k, kIn, kFin, kInc}];]
(* Out: {90.5666, Null} *)
```

This is on a two-core machine, so the benefits from parallelization may be even better on higher core-count machines.

---

Having said that, the definitions of `kList` and `kFList` can be simplified:

```
kList = Range[kIn, kFin, kInc];
kFList = ConstantArray[kList, Length@Transpose@eigeng];
```

Comment: Better additions, like `kList` and `kFList` and `DistributeDefinitions[kdel, kIn, kFin, kInc]`. I think further simplifications are not possible. For `Graphics` also. As from my side, speed I got from previously is about 0.5s. Less but good

Comment: @L.K. I think another important consideration, even for the preparation of the graphics objects, is whether you do need to try and plot all those points. There is no way that you can actually *see* that many points on a computer screen, or in most media printouts, so perhaps pruning the list to a more manageable size (plotting every ten points etc) would help.

Comment: @L.K. From a more fundamental standpoint, your matrix is very sparse, and has a relatively simple structure. I think it might be worth it to see if you can manipulate the math to determine whether you want (or need) to calculate *all* eigenvalues: there are numerical methods to calculate only a fraction of those, e.g. by magnitude (see the `Method` options for `Eigenvalues`). Perhaps some clever pencil-and-paper math might reduce the size of your problem.

Comment: thanks for the valuable informations. For sure I will check the possibilities as you have mentioned.